# Interpretation of simulation of chi-square distribution?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, simulation

I created a simulation study of distribution of $n$ values in an $m$-dimensional table under the assumption that the true distribution is uniform. The goal is to find out why we should be careful about using the Chi-square test when the expected number of elements per cell is small.  (The results are below.)

If I am not mistaken, the density plot of 20 values in an 8-dimensional table has "holes" in it because there are comparatively little possible combinations of 20 elements across 8 cells. However, I do not understand why does this cast doubt about the validity of the chi-square test? In both cases, the empirical chi-square distribution follows the shape of the theoretical chi-square distribution, and in both cases the empirical and theoretical mean and variance closely align.

Could anybody help me with relating the results of my simulation to the general idea about chi-square tests?

[image: 20 values across 8 cells]
[image: 80 values across 10 cells]

Comment: In the chi-square test we calculate  $\frac{(O−E)^2}{E}$ for each pair of observed and expected values then sum them all up. $E$ should not be close to zero.

Comment: What exactly "casts doubt on the validity" of the chi-squared test?  For applying the chi-squared distribution you need to examine the *cumulative* distribution function, not the histogram!  Also, the size of the test matters: you will come to one conclusion if testing at the 5% level and another if testing at the 0.1% level.